# JSON in HTML - how to clean object which is a string

Tags: html, json

I have a string that appears like an object but actually is a string. It does not look very nice and comfortable to read. Are there any possibilities to change this? `JSON.parse` does not seem to work because not every element meets the requirements to be a JSON object. For example, number 0 does not have any quotes. Any ideas?

```
{'credits': [{'api_user_id': '1', 'amount': '897.26', 'l_amount': '0.00', 'period': '90', 'charge': '338.77', 'o_charge': '338.77', 'created': '2019-11-20 12:46:56', 'registered': '2019-11-20 12:46:56', 'expire': '2020-02-20', 'max_delay': '0', 'delay': 0, 'debt': '0.00', 'late_fee': '0.00', 's_payment': '0.00', 'discount_code': '', 'description': 'reg', 'p_amount': '0.00', 'paid': '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'origin_id': 0, 'confirmed': '0', 'l_interest': '0.00', 'l_administrative_fee': '0.00', 'l_cinterest': '0.00', 'l_late_fee': '0.00', 'l_penalty': '0.00', 'l_s_amount': '0.00', 'l_s_interest': '0.00', 'l_s_administrative_fee': '0.00', 'important': 0, 'schedule': [{'date': '2019-12-20', 'day': 30, o: '897.26', 'c': '0.00', 'p': '160.61', 's': '251.40', 'amount': '412.01'}, ]}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to [deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) JSON. You might want to create a C# solution. You might want to look into the following method: `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Object>(json);`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp) might also help you as a reference. Please add to your question what you already tried. For any reference when asking questions, please visit [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure to add anything you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is this that text is created dynamically, and I can not change what I get. Problem is when I have many txts which are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so problem with your string is You have used single quotes.
So instead of this:

```
var str = {'credits': [{'api_user_id': '1', 'amount': '897.26','l_amount': '0.00', 'period': '90', 'charge': '338.77', 'o_charge': '338.77', 'created': '2019-11-20 12:46:56', 'registered': 2019-11-20 12:46:56', 'expire': '2020-02-20','max_delay': '0', 'delay': 0, 'debt': '0.00', 'late_fee': '0.00', 's_payment': '0.00', 'discount_code': '', 'description': 'reg', 'p_amount': '0.00', 'paid': '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'origin_id': 0, 'confirmed': '0', 'l_interest': '0.00', 'l_administrative_fee': '0.00', 'l_cinterest': '0.00', 'l_late_fee':'0.00', 'l_penalty': '0.00', 'l_s_amount': '0.00', 'l_s_interest': '0.00', 'l_s_administrative_fee': '0.00', 'important': 0, 'schedule': [{'date': '2019-12-20', 'day': 30, o: '897.26', 'c': '0.00', 'p': '160.61', 's': '251.40','amount': '412.01'}, ]}
```

Use your string like this and JSON.parse will work

```
const str = '{"credits":[{"api_user_id":"1","amount":"897.26","l_amount":"0.00","period":"90","charge":"338.77","o_charge":"338.77","created":"2019-11-20 12:46:56","registered":"2019-11-20 12:46:56","expire":"2020-02-20","max_delay":"0","delay":0,"debt":"0.00","late_fee":"0.00","s_payment":"0.00","discount_code":"","description":"reg","p_amount":"0.00","paid":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","origin_id":0,"confirmed":"0","l_interest":"0.00","l_administrative_fee":"0.00","l_cinterest":"0.00","l_late_fee":"0.00","l_penalty":"0.00","l_s_amount":"0.00","l_s_interest":"0.00","l_s_administrative_fee":"0.00","important":0,"schedule":[{"date":"2019-12-20","day":30,"o":"897.26","c":"0.00","p":"160.61","s":"251.40","amount":"412.01"}]}]}'
const strData = JSON.parse(str);


console.log(strData)
```

Comment: Accept if you find it useful:)

Comment: I can not change this by hand. Because i have many difference txt. This what I pass is one of many others. So that's my question, is there any other way to clean this?

Comment: are the strings results of an HTTP call?

Comment: Can you post the receiving end where you are getting the responce

Comment: The http request is on backend side, I have to do only frontend, thats why I asked it is possible I can change it in somehow

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj1 = eval("(" + json + ')');
```

or this help https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/